# How to breadcrumbs get all collection name and url in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, breadcrumbs

I am beginner Shopify developer, I have customise collection.liquid page. How to customise breadcrumb show selected collection name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/navigation/add-breadcrumbs) documentation.

The title number 5 show how to use breadcrumb for collection page, look : 
`{% elsif template contains 'collection' and collection.handle %}
[...]
{% elsif ... %}`